# Code reuse using an abstract class:hurdles

Tags: c#

I have two classes. Class A and Class B. They both inherit from an abstract class. There is a method in both the classes that has the exact same code and I am trying to move it to the abstract class

The method goes like this in Class A:

```
public void updateResult(OutputA output)
{

    var Class c = new Class C();
    var result = c.process();

    output.result = result;
}
```

Similarly the method is in Class B with an OutputB parameter. The property result is common in classes A and B.

Both types OutputA and OutputB derive from a base type Output.

When I move the method to the abstract class and use the parameter type as Output, the compiler is not able to recognize the result property.

What would be a better way of solving this problem so that the method can be moved to an abstract class and can be used by Class A and Class B.

Comment: Sounds like the result property isn't in the Output base class, so you need to refactor so it is!

Comment: Abstract classes are used as a form of generalization, but you need to use explicit concrete types in implementations, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an interface that exposes the `result` property and implement it in both the `OutputA` and `OutputB` classes, then you can pass your parameter as the interface type.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure the `result` property of the `OutputA` and `OutputB` class is defined in the `Output` class and is public, and then set the parameter type of `updateResult` to `Output` (as you've discussed in your question).

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the Output parameter to the appropriate type, OutputA or OutputB.  If you post your code, then I can see where the casts need to happen.